# MySQL very large INSERT ... SELECT or Application level batching of SELECT then INSERTS

Tags: mysql, node.js

Which is a better idea if I have very large amounts of data to process (need a SELECT) and then insert into another table (INSERT)

- A long `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, or potentially a stored procedure
- OR application level `SELECT` 1st process creating batches of `INSERT INTO table () VALUES (), (), ...`

Would a `INSERT ... SELECT` hang the server? Or perhaps run out of memory? Suppose the SELECT results in a large dataset say 1 million records (but with little data, ~2+ columns. ID columns so its an INT)

**UPDATE:** Application is using NodeJS

Comment: the devil's in the details. Brace yourself for the potential of deadlocks

Comment: @Drew do you mean something described https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/07/12/insert-into-select-performance-with-innodb-tables/? What they suggested will help? SELECT INTO OUTFILE then LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: I would focus on Sylvain261's ideas on percona, and perhaps describe how often this is occurring, what others are doing. Also, the facebook experience could suggest the load data infile could target a secondary table for the risk-adverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping all the data processing in the database is generally the best solution, from a performance perspective.

Handling a million rows should be okay.  Of course, there are other considerations:  indexes and triggers, for instance.  Also, if the insert is blocking other queries, than that is another issue.  But in general, a million rows from a `select` should be okay.

Comment: Is there a limit to the max rows I can expect from my SELECT query before I need to batch them in some ways? If I need to batch them, how should I do that?

Comment: @JiewMeng . . . Your best bet is to put the rows into a temporary table and then batch them into the final table.

Comment: thought of that, but I will have to generate a unique table name for this temporary table isit? and remove it when its done? I was thinking if MySQL can handle that in a `INSERT ... SELECT` query that will be great! But I guess it doesnt batch things up? And if the SELECT query results in too much data, it might cause the memory to be used up?

Comment: @JiewMeng . . . I would suggest you investigate `create temporary table as`.

Answer (score 1):

I consider this answer to be an addendum to Gordon's response.  In the first option,

> A long `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, or potentially a stored procedure

The entire operation is taking place in the database, so the only network overhead is in sending the query itself, which is negligible.  However, in the second option,

> application level `SELECT` 1st process creating batches of `INSERT INTO table () VALUES (), (), ...`

You are first retrieving *all* the data which you want to insert into your application layer, and then sending all of it back to the database.  The network overhead here is much larger than the first option.  In addition, the application layer (e.g. Java) is not very good at doing database things (but MySQL is).  Handling the data in the app layer also might be error prone.

So I would go with the first option if possible.

Comment: Makes sense, tho I should mention I am using NodeJS, so perhaps non-block IO helps abit here.

Comment: I don't think my answer would change since NodeJS is a server side technology (as is J2EE).